# How to test RSpec custom matchers

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I am developing RSpec custom matchers like [rspec-dns](https://github.com/spotify/rspec-dns) and [rspec-ssltls](https://github.com/otahi/rspec-ssltls).

What is the most effective way for testing RSpec custom matchers?

I tests custom matchers(means a test target is a custom matcher). I can tests normal cases of custom matchers like as follows.

[rspec_ssltls/have_certificate_spec.rb](https://github.com/otahi/rspec-ssltls/blob/master/spec/rspec_ssltls/have_certificate_spec.rb)

```
## Having certificate
it 'can evaluate having certificate' do
  stub_ssl_socket(peer_cert_chain: [nil])
  expect('www.example.com:443').not_to have_certificate
  stub_ssl_socket(peer_cert_chain: [example_cert])
  expect('www.example.com:443').to have_certificate
end
```

But the RSpec test cases fail if I test error cases. I want to test error cases can be errors.

Comment: check out rspec's [`raise_error`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/raise-error-matcher)

Comment: I see how to test error cases with custom matchers but don't see how to test error cases of custom matchers with the reference for [raise_error](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/raise-error-matcher).

Answer (score 0):

If the failing assertion is

```
expect('www.example.com:443').not_to have_certificate
```

with a message 'url does have a certificate'
then you can test it with

```
expect { expect('www.example.com:443').not_to have_certificate }.to raise_error 'url does have certificate'
```

If you only want to test part of the failure message, you can use

```
expect { expect('www.example.com:443').not_to have_certificate }.to raise_error(/does have/)
```